# Data Versioning in Cassandra with CQL3

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm struggling with the data modelling for the use cases I'm trying to satisfy. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575560/versioning-in-cassandra) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183945/ways-to-implement-data-versioning-in-cassandra) and even [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/535LyWOJKsc) but they're not exactly what I needed.

I have this basic table:

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
    itemid_version text,       
    xml_payload text,
    insert_time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (itemid_version)
);
```

`itemid` is actually a UUID (and unique for all documents), and `version` is an int (version 0 is the "first" version).  `xml_payload` is the full XML doc, and can get quite big.  Yes, I'm essentially creating a versioned document store.

As you can see, I concatenated the two to create a primary key and I'll get to why I did this later as I explain the requirements and/or use cases:

- Use-Case 1: user needs to get the single (1) doc, user knows the item id and version (not necessarily the latest)
- Use-Case 2: user needs to get the single (1) doc, user knows the item id but does not know the latest version
- Use-Case 3: user needs the version history of a single (1) doc
- Use-Case 4: user needs to get the list (1 or more) of docs, user knows the item id AND version (not necessarily the latest)

I will be writing the client code that will perform the use cases, please excuse the syntax as I'm trying to be language-agnostic.

First one's straightforward:

```
$itemid_version = concat($itemid, $version)
$doc = csql("select * from documents where itemid_version = {0};" 
    -f $itemid_version)
```

Now to satisfy the 2nd and 3rd use cases, I am adding the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE document_versions (
    itemid uuid,
    version int,
    PRIMARY KEY (itemid, version)
) WITH clustering order by (version DESC);
```

The new records will be added as new docs and new versions of existing docs are created.

Now we have this (use case #2):

```
$latest_itemid, $latest_version = csql("select itemid, 
    version from document_versions where item_id = {0} 
    order by version DESC limit 1;" -f $itemid)
$itemid_version = concat($latest_itemid, $latest_version)
$doc = csql("select * from documents where itemid_version = {0};" 
    -f $itemid_version)
```

and this (use case #3):

```
$versions = csql("select version from document_versions where item_id = {0}" 
    -f $itemid)
```

For the 3rd requirement, I am adding yet another table:

```
CREATE TABLE latest_documents (
    itemid uuid,
    version int,
    PRIMARY KEY (itemid, version)
)
```

The records are inserted for new docs, records are updated for existing docs.

And now we have this:

```
$latest_itemids, $latest_versions = csql("select itemid, version 
    from latest_documents where item_id in ({0})" -f $itemid_list.toCSV())

foreach ($one_itemid in $latest_itemids, $one_version in $latest_versions)
    $itemid_version = concat($latest_itemid, $latest_version)
    $latest_docs.append(
        cql("select * from documents where itemid_version = {0};" 
        -f $itemid_version))
```

Now I hope it's clear why I concatenated `itemid` and `version` to create an index for `documents` as opposed to creating a compound key: I cannot have `OR` in the `WHERE` clause in `SELECT`.

You can assume that only one process will do the inserts/updates so you don't need to worry about consistency or isolation issues.

Am I on the right track here? There are quite a number of things that doesn't sit well with me...but mainly because I don't understand Cassandra yet:

- I feel that the primary key for `documents` should be a composite of (itemid, version) but I can't satisfy use case #4 (return a list from a query)...I can't possibly use a separate SELECT statement for each document due to the performance hit (network overhead)...or can (should) I?
- It requires 2 trips to get a document if the version is not known beforehand. This is probably a compromise I have to live with, unless maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually very similar to your solution except that you can store all the versions and be able to fetch the 'latest' version just from one table (`document_versions`).

In most cases, I think you can get what you want in a single `SELECT` except use case #2 which requires fetching the most recent version of a document where a `SELECT` is first needed on `document_versions`.

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
        itemid_version text,
        xml_payload text,
        insert_time timestamp,
        PRIMARY KEY (itemid_version)
);

CREATE TABLE document_versions (
        itemid text,
        version int,
        PRIMARY KEY (itemid, version)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (version DESC);


INSERT INTO documents (itemid_version, xml_payload, insert_time) VALUES ('doc1-1', '<?xml>1st</xml>', '2014-05-21 18:00:00');
INSERT INTO documents (itemid_version, xml_payload, insert_time) VALUES ('doc1-2', '<?xml>2nd</xml>', '2014-05-21 18:00:00');
INSERT INTO documents (itemid_version, xml_payload, insert_time) VALUES ('doc2-1', '<?xml>1st</xml>', '2014-05-21 18:00:00');
INSERT INTO documents (itemid_version, xml_payload, insert_time) VALUES ('doc2-2', '<?xml>2nd</xml>', '2014-05-21 18:00:00');

INSERT INTO document_versions (itemid, version) VALUES ('doc1', 1);
INSERT INTO document_versions (itemid, version) VALUES ('doc1', 2);
INSERT INTO document_versions (itemid, version) VALUES ('doc2', 1);
INSERT INTO document_versions (itemid, version) VALUES ('doc2', 2);
```

- Use-Case 1: user needs to get the single (1) doc, user knows the item id and version (not necessarily the latest)

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM documents WHERE itemid_version = 'doc1-2';
  ```
- Use-Case 2: user needs to get the single (1) doc, user knows the item id but does not know the latest version (you need to feed the concatenated `itemid` + `version` from the result of the first query into the second query)

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM document_versions WHERE itemid = 'doc2' LIMIT 1;

  SELECT * FROM documents WHERE itemid_version = 'doc2-2';
  ```
- Use-Case 3: user needs the version history of a single (1) doc

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM document_versions WHERE itemid = 'doc2';
  ```
- Use-Case 3: user needs to get the list (1 or more) of docs, user knows the item id AND version (not necessarily the latest)

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM documents WHERE itemid_version IN ('doc1-2', 'doc2-1');
  ```

Comment: thanks @reggoodwin...as for use case #4, i know it's the use case that throws a monkey wrench here as your solution would have worked for me if i didn't have that requirement.  basically, for use case #4 it boils down to "entitlements"--i.e., some users are only entitled up to a _certain_ version of a doc (again, specific users may _not_ be entitled to the latest version).

Comment: actually, for this approach `SELECT * FROM documents where itemid IN ('doc1', 'doc2');` returns *ALL* versions of the documents, not just the latest.

Comment: Dexter, thanks for flagging up problem with my use case #4 example. I had not tested that last query before adding some final INSERTs. I've now re-submitted a different code example that I hope works better. It is quite similar to your solution actually.

Comment: Actually this approach is a Cassandra antipattern since you are trying to minimize multiple reads.  The first rule of thumb is that each table should be constructcted to serve a specific query.

Comment: Any chance I can use the key-value system in tabular data to version it(data) using Cassandra? My aim is to provide user the insert, delete and update patch each time the data comes in and the version is to be formed. Note: these patches are the candidate version compared to current latest version.

Answer (score 5):

Let's see if we can come up with a model in a top-down fashion starting from your queries:

```sql
CREATE TABLE document_versions (
  itemid uuid,
  name text STATIC,
  version int,   
  xml_payload text,
  insert_time timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY ((itemid), version)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (version DESC);
```

- Use-Case 1: user needs to get the single (1) doc, user knows the item id and version (not necessarily the latest)

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM document_versions 
    WHERE itemid = ? and version = ?;
  ```
- Use-Case 2: user needs to get the single (1) doc, user knows the item id but does not know the latest version

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM document_versions
    WHERE itemid = ? limit 1;
  ```
- Use-Case 3: user needs the version history of a single (1) doc

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM document_versions 
    WHERE itemid = ?
  ```
- Use-Case 4: user needs to get the list (1 or more) of docs, user knows the item id AND version (not necessarily the latest)

  ````sql
  SELECT * FROM documents 
    WHERE itemid = 'doc1' and version IN ('1', '2');
   ```
  ````

One table for all these queries is the correct approach.

I would suggest taking the Datastax free online course: [DS220 Data Modeling](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220-data-modeling)

Comment: indeed, this is probably the better answer for Cassandra v2.2 and above [since it added support for `IN` clause for _any_ partition field](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause).  note that i asked the question well over a year before [v2.2 release](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-2-2).